# Sort Result from INDEX+MATCH in 1 formula - duplicate sorting value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think I found pretty much what I'm looking for from the post below but the problem is, if there is a duplicate value that used for sorting the result repeat the first value instead of going to the next one.
For example if there is score of 1200 twice with different name it only return the first found name twice.

[Building Sorting/Ranking into an Index Match Array formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71533097/building-sorting-ranking-into-an-index-match-array-formula)

If there is another
1200 | Bears | Bill (different name)

I expect it to return
Andy
Bill
Paul
Larry
Frank

With a current formula suggested in the link it is returning
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(($C$3:$C$10=$F$3)*($B$3:$B$10=LARGE(IF($C$3:$C$10=$F$3,$B$3:$B$10),ROWS($1:1))))*ROW($D$3:$D$10),1)),"")

Andy
Andy
Paul
Larry
Frank

I try to add countif at the end but it all mess up, any recommendation please? This is for Excel 2013.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: So I use this - easy to edit for 5 or 10 etc. If it helps then give it a vote. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike Hi, thank you, if I understand it correctly this will need a helper column, right? Is there a way to do it without any helper column? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, it is guaranteed to deal with duplicates which is why I set it up - I actually use it with classes of 40 students to track attendance. If you wish to edit it to make it work in one column I wish you luck. But surely you have a spare column or have you used 64000? It can be set to work on a separate sheet if necessary…

Comment: Okay, thanks. It could be a fall back plan of course, but looking around I see a few different possible options with countif or Row-Row but I just couldn't get it to work ^^".  Thanks again for your input, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well I played with countif, row() etc etc and that was what worked to deal with duplicates and 5 classes of 40 students with each class having the source data on a separate sheet.

Comment: If you want it to be a simple formula, my best advise would be to upgrade your excel to 2021 or better Office 365.

Comment: @P.b Thanks, it is a work station I don't have authority to make decision on those things :)

Comment: @SolarMike Hi, may I ask what is the ROW($1:$40) mean in your suggested formula, please? Why 40? And can it be like $A$1:$A$40? Thank you for your help.